# Docker: service 'image' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, openvpn

I'm install openvpn-status and npm install not work for me so I use docker instead. And when using docker-compose I got the error:

```
docker-compose up docker-compose.yml
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string.
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  openvpn-status:
  image: auspexeu/openvpn-status
  container_name: openvpn-status
  volumes:
    - './status-cfg/cfg.json:/usr/src/app/cfg.json'
  ports:
    - 8080:3013
  restart: "unless-stopped"
```

Very appreciate with any solutions from you :D
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is incorrect. With the version 2-3 format, under services is your service names, and under those service names are the settings for each service.

```
version: '2'
services:
  openvpn-status:
    image: auspexeu/openvpn-status
    container_name: openvpn-status
    volumes:
      - './status-cfg/cfg.json:/usr/src/app/cfg.json'
    ports:
      - 8080:3013
    restart: "unless-stopped"
```